# NullPointerException on the setAdapter() function

Tags: android

I have no idea what to do. The application keeps crashing, and after hours of searching for the problem, I got nothing. Does anyone know where the problem is?

Here are all the variables I declared:

```
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

ViewPager mViewPager;
public ArrayList<String> numberList = new ArrayList<String>();
public ListView listOfItems;
```

This is the **onCreate** function:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    listOfItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    numberList.add("Hello");
    numberList.add("World");

    StableArrayAdapter listAdapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numberList);

    listOfItems.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

}
```

[ *EDIT* ] This is the **fragment_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/addButton" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

It is also giving the following error log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.adnan.figura/com.adnan.figura.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at com.adnan.figura.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:63)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
```

Comment: Can you post your error logs and the .xml layout file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to say

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

first, and then findViewById for your ListView.

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize the listOfItems below setContentView.

Should be like this:

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

listOfItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

And also check if R.id.listView exist on your R.layout.activity_main

Answer (score 1):

You have a very basic mistake which can be solved in seconds.

Please change the ordering of the two lines to this.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
listOfItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

First you need to set the content, then the Views will be created and then you can use findViewById().

**You are actually trying to find views before even creating them**. Hope I could solve your problem and explain you the mistake.